# Managing third party resources using deps is a good practice in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

For my project i'm using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) charting library and [markItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) jQuery editor. I'd like to keep them up to date at a minimum effort. I've put this in my `deps` file:

```
[Highcharts]
    git=https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com.git
    target=highcharts

[markItUp]
    git=https://github.com/markitup/1.x.git
    target=markItUp
```

And then importing using assetic:

```
{% javascripts filter='?yui_js' output='js/application.js'
    '../app/Resources/public/js/jquery-*.js'
    '../vendor/highcharts/js/highcharts.src.js'
    '../vendor/markItUp/markitup/js/jquery.markitup.src.js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" ></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

All works fine as expected. Is this a good practice? Is there any downside in managing javascript libraries this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using deps to add the library is best practice. You should, however, do two things:

1. If you have source control (git, svn) make sure it is ignoring the library folders. Best practice is to not include outside libraries in your source control, and instead run vendors:install when you deploy to load the libraries.
2. In many cases, you should add a hash or version number to lock the library to a specific version. This might not apply to your case (since you said you want to always be on the latest version), but is critical for things like Symfony bundles. Otherwise, when you run vendors:install, you run the risk of updating everything to an unsupported version (like, say, updating a bundle to a version for SF2.1 when your on 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

It's good as soon as your vendors don't break something.
So, if you need to be safe, it would be better to lock your vendors to a specific hash (in deps.lock). Alternatively, you can specify a version in your deps file, but only if git repository has branches/tags.
See Standard Edition deps files for examples.